# Is it okay to cut a 2 row 8-pin DIP socket for IC to stripboard connections?

Tags: stripboard

I have a fatal short circuit (connecting 0V to 5V) on a very tedious stripboard project because I was given an 8-pin 2-row DIP socket (shown below) that has a short circuit between pins 2 and 3 (the two middle pins on the left-most side) instead of an 8-pin 2-row DIP socket where none of the pins are connected to each other.

Do I have to de-solder all ten of the sockets I have used and solder new ones in (painful) or could I simply manually cut the socket between pins 2 and 3 with some sort of razor blade (please recommend a better tool)?

[image: 8-pin DIP socket for IC to breadboard]

Edit: it was suggested that no sockets are manufactured with short circuits so I am guessing there must be something wrong with the board. I have S-C, O-C and continuity tested the board (as well as made some extra track breaks) and still I cannot see why the top most rail is shorted to the bottom most rail... Most of this board was not by work but it is my task to finish it off (groan).

Topside and bottomside pictures shown below (shorted pins shown in red):
[image: TOPSIDE]

[image: BOTTOMSIDE]

Comment: Do you mean that the sockets were manufactured with two pins shorted?  I've never seen such a socket, so I would suggest you carefully inspect your board and soldering for shorts before blaming the sockets. (and pin 4 is a corner pin - leftmost pin  on the top row in your picture).

Comment: I meant pins 3 and 5, thanks for pointing that out! I am quite confident that my board cannot be the issue but I will post it on here to show you! Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Pins 3 and 5 are not on the same side. Check your pin numbering convention.

Comment: Ah... I got it now. Pins 2 and 3 (center on the left-most side). Thanks! (It's late at night)

Comment: Referring to your picture, IC socket pins are conventionally numbered 1 to 4 right to left on the top row, and 5 - 8 left to right on the bottom row (when viewed from the top side, counter-clockwise around the socket or IC).  Pins 1 and 8 will be at the end with the notch in the molding.

Comment: @PeterBennett Is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package#/media/File:Pin_numbering_01_Pengo.svg) not the correct method?

Comment: Yes, your link shows the correct numbering, and matches my description (at least, as I read my description...)

Comment: I do not follow why the two middle-most pins of the top left row are pins 2 and 3... Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I don't believe you, there is no sane reason for a socket manufacturer to produce such a part. I'm looking forward to seeing this board of yours :)

Comment: When measuring resistance between the offending pins, with the socket not mounted to the board, do you meashre a short circuit? Can you show a picture of the underside of a socket ( loose, not on the board.)?

Comment: Mark up the photo of the socket with the pin numbers you are using.

Comment: No obvious shorts but I can see you're new to this, someone more experienced would have used the resistors as jumpers, and perhaps more than one negative rail (ground).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments I realised there was a short under the correcting wires on the underside of the board.

Note to self: Manufacturers are not evil and do not produce shorted sockets.

Thanks again to all the commenters and the helpful tips!

Comment: Use resistors as wires (jumpers) and you will have fewer wires and solder joints to "debug" in the future. Good luck.

Comment: Please accept your answer so that this old question stops getting automatically churned to the top of the question list.